# Setup Django Blog Comments

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

If I wanted to setup comments for a blog in Django, and I wanted people to be able to reply to comments (like a normal blog), meaning each comment would have to know if it's a comment on another comment or not, would I set the model fields like this?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey(Comment, blank=True, null=True)
```

Is that correct? And how would I display them in a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a hierarchical comments application seems too easy at first look but believe me it is not that simple. There are too many edge cases and security issues. So if this is a real project i would suggest you to use [disqus](http://disqus.com/), any other hosted solution or (now deprecated) [comments framework](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments).

On the other hand if you are just trying to learn how things done or playing around, your code seems fair enough so far. But you should consider [Django's built-in content types framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) instead of a direct foreign key relationship. That way you can relate a comment object to any other object. (a blog post or another comment). Take a look at comment frameworks models.py and you will see it.

```
class BaseCommentAbstractModel(models.Model):
"""
An abstract base class that any custom comment models probably should
subclass.
"""

# Content-object field
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
        verbose_name=_('content type'),
        related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s")
object_pk = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
```

Also take a look at `RenderCommentListNode`in [comment framework template tags](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/templatetags/comments.py). You should write a recursive function in order to get and display hierarchical comments.

You have to consider cases like:

- What will happen if a user deletes a comment?
- How should we delete comments? Should we actually remove it from database or should we set an attribute like `deleted`
- How should we deal with permissions and level of user access?
- If we let anonymous users to comment, what information do we need from them.
- How to check human validation? Is captcha enough?

Happy hacking.